# ASP.NET MVC Helpers, create helpers for two properties of model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need create helpers for two properties of model
For example

```
@Html.TestFor(m => m.Item1, m=>m.Item2)
```

And so how can write method for this helper?

For example

```
public static MvcHtmlString TestFor<TModel, TValue>
          (this HtmlHelper<TModel> self,
          Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
...
}
```

It is method for only one property of model. 
How can write for few property?
Thank for ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use multiple expressions in your helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TestFor<TModel, TValue>
          (this HtmlHelper<TModel> self,
          Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> secondExpression)
{
...
}
```

or use `params` to indicate multiple expressions and work with array of expressions later:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TestFor<TModel, TValue>
          (this HtmlHelper<TModel> self,
          params Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>[] expressions)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Razor code is written only in `cshtml` files, here you will deal with `TagBuilder` to build html output, but generally it won't differ much from default html helpers

Comment: I ask about @Html.TestFor(m => m.Item1, m=>m.Item2)

Comment: Of course this will work, it's just passing parameters to a method.

Comment: I came up with the same thing as the second idea shown here. However clever, it will only work if the type (TValue) is the same for all of the expressions.  Which is sadly almost always not the case :-(.

Answer (score 3):

if property types different each other use like this :

```
public static MvcHtmlString ImageFor<TModel, TProperty, KProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expressionImageProperty,//this is HttpPostedFile
            Expression<Func<TModel, KProperty>> expressionImageIdProperty,//this property is ID for image that store in database
            object filehtmlAttributes, object imageBoxHtmlAttributes)//html attributes for html controls
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var fileattr = new RouteValueDictionary(filehtmlAttributes);
            if (!fileattr.ContainsKey("id"))
                fileattr.Add("id", string.Format("ImageForFile_{0}", ((MemberExpression)expressionImageProperty.Body).Member.Name));
            fileattr.Add("type", "file");
            if (!fileattr.ContainsKey("class"))
                fileattr.Add("class", "form-control");
            fileattr.Add("onchange", "readURL(this);");
            sb.Append((string)htmlHelper.TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(expressionImageProperty, fileattr).ToHtmlString());

            TagBuilder tagImg = new TagBuilder("img");
            tagImg.Attributes.Add("id", string.Format("ImageForFileViewer_{0}", ((MemberExpression)expressionImageProperty.Body).Member.Name));

            if (htmlHelper.ViewData.Model == null)
                tagImg.Attributes.Add("src",
                    new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("GetImage", "ImageManagement",
                        new { imageId = "0" }));
            else
            {
                var modelImageId = expressionImageIdProperty.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model).ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelImageId))
                    modelImageId = "0";
                tagImg.Attributes.Add("src",
                    new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("GetImage", "ImageManagement", //ImageManagementController get FileResult
                        new
                        {
                            imageId = modelImageId,thumb=true,size="small"
                        }));
            }

            if (imageBoxHtmlAttributes != null)//
                tagImg.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(imageBoxHtmlAttributes));//

            sb.Append(tagImg.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

            sb.Append((string)htmlHelper.HiddenFor<TModel, KProperty>(expressionImageIdProperty).ToHtmlString()); //for update

            sb.AppendLine(
               EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IPageScriptManager>()//this is simple mvc script manager resolved from IOC
                                 .ScriptInclude<CommonResourceAccessor>("imageFor" + "_script",
                                                                        "***.WebFramework.Resources.ImageFor.js")//if you have some js file add as resource
                                 .Render().ToString());
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: do you have any insight related to this posting that you could share? I am trying to build a control that allows me to pass in many properties. Any catch 22's?